# Session with cross page postback asp.net

Tags: asp.net, postback, session-variables

I need to bind some variables on a session but they disappear after cross page postback.

What would be the best way to store variables on the server side in case of cross page postback?

Thank you very much
Cheers

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get you. are you trying to get session value from variable which is assigned by session["user"], on the cross page postback? If then, Why don't you use simply Session["user"] everywhere?

Comment: sorry I was confused I thought the session gets cleared but it doesn't, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Session-Cookie/GetvaluefromsessionincrosspagepostingVB.htm